# Betadispers plot, how to change the labelling

Tags: r

I wanted to plot my betadispers results. It is a deafult plot for this analysis so i cannot really change the parameters. Does anyone know what to do to change those labels so that they don't cover each other?
Thank you for your help

I tried delete labelling
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2R28.jpg)